# Do we have to submit a Paid Application Agreement if I intend to fix a price for my app @ 0.99$

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, price

Do we have to submit a Paid Application Agreement if I intend to fix a price for my app @ 0.99$

1. Is the agreement for a longer period or can be renewed after a certain interval
2. Can we update the pricing once the app is inside the App Store

Comment: If you want to be paid - yes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to submit the agreement no matter what the price is - as long as it is not free.

The agreement runs for a longer period, but Apple will periodically make updates and changes, and at that point you'll have to agree to it again.

You can update the pricing at any time both before it is listed on the App Store, and while it is listed on the App Store.